# ExtJS 5.0 - which function to override to add custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

I want to dynamically add a rule to existing CSS using code like this:

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
// Code omitted to determine which sheet to use, so just defaulting
// to last style sheet. Also, error checking code omitted.
var sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
sheet.insertRule('.overlay {float: left; opacity: 0.8;}', -1);
```

However, I can have the above code only in overrides. Is there a function I can override after the CSS is loaded but before the components are displayed? If not, where is the earliest I can change the CSS?

Comment: either the style config of a component or cls config for own css classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can have the above code only in overrides. Is there a function I can
>   override after the CSS is loaded but before the components are
>   displayed?

If you put your overrides in the right place (such as the "overrides" folder in your app structure), they will be processed *before* any component is rendered (effectively, displayed). So that should work for you.

Also note that Ext JS has an utility for dynamic CSS manipulations — [Ext.util.CSS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.CSS), so using it instead of "low-level" style alterations is recommended.

Comment: Thank you, I put it in override of `init` of view controller. Seems to work okay.